# Storing pointers in std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have some class A that contains many data members. When I create a vector of this class `std::vector<A> vec;` and call `vec.push_back(A(...));`, some times the vector will have to reallocate memory and move all the previous objects to the new memory. This will copy many A objects. The solution I found is storing pointers to A objects that are allocated on the heap instead. This will make the vector copy 4-byte integers which is okay, but I've never seen anyone do it, so I'm not sure if it's the correct approach.

Is this something standard?

Comment: This is very common to have a vector of pointers. Then you simply do `vec.push_back(new A( ... ));`

Comment: use make_unique or make_shared to manage ownership rather than using new.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to show how common is `std::vector<A>` versus `std::vector<A *>`. I grepped `llvm 6.0.0` since it is considered by many to be a leading standard of CPP development. Here are the results:

```
$ grep -rn "vector<.*\*" | wc -l
613
$ grep -rn "vector<.*" | wc -l
1707
```

So I guess this example gives a taste of which flavor is more common.
Of course that this is only an example of one code base...

Comment: It's counting the number of variable declarations (and `using` and `typedef`) are done with a pointer to a class (613) from the pool of all variable declarations (and `using` and `typedef`). So for this particular `llvm 6.0.0` code base, about a third of vectors are with pointers to classes. That's pretty common.